# FButton и слушатель для него

Tags: android, button, интерфейс, android-button

Для создания кнопок использовал библиотеку [FButton](https://github.com/hoang8f/android-flat-button). Затем пытался добавить ему слушатель через Butter Knife, не получилось.

```
@OnClick(R.id.startButton)
```

Затем попробовал cоздать объект кнопки и дать ему слушателя. То же не сработало.

```
FButton btn = (FButton)findViewById(R.id.startButton);
View.OnClickListener btnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(context, MenuActivity.class));
        }
    };
btn.setOnClickListener(btnClick);
```

Не помогло, кнопка не реагирует(

Comment: btn всегда null

Comment: Если btn null, значит у вас что-то не так в разметке/коде. Проверьте, что у вас совпадает ID кнопки в разметке/коде. Что вы загрузили правильную разметку.

Comment: Если ещё до сих пор не решили проблему - выложите полностью ваш onCreate с Butter

Comment: Спасибо @ЮрийСПб. Заметил, что не использовал setContentView. Случайно удалил. Скорее всего что-то бы да получилось, только вот появилась непонятная ошибка.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.-1

Краснеет на "R.". Пробовал сделать "Clean project", но выходит эта ошибка или 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (no error message)

Почистить не могу, пересобрать тоже(

Comment: @manGust, возможно у вас что-то не так в зависимостях. Поробуйте их понизить. У вас наверное почти везде 24 версия всего стоит.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб. Спасибо за помощь, проблема решена!))

Answer (score 1):

Удалил setContentView по невнимательности.
С ошибкой справился просто. Удалил всё из каталога libraries, затем Sync Project и Clean Project. Проблема исчезла, кнопки работают. Правда butter knife, по @OnClick() всё равно работать отказывается.